# Properties of Lévy's metric

Tags: probability-theory, weak-convergence, probability-limit-theorems

Let $\mathcal{P}$ be the set of measures on $(\mathbb{R},B(\mathbb{R}))$, for 
$\mu, \sigma \in \mathcal{P},$ let $d(\mu,\sigma)=\inf(\epsilon>0;\forall x \in \mathbb{R},F_{\sigma}(x-\epsilon)-\epsilon \leq F_{\mu}(x) \leq F_{\sigma}(x+\epsilon)+\epsilon)$ where $F$ denotes the distribution function of a measure.

We can prove that $(\mathcal{P},d)$ is a metric space and that $(\mu_n)_n$ converges weakly to $\mu$ if and only if $\lim_nd(\mu_n,\mu)=0$.

I am studying some properties of this space such as completeness and separability.

For the separability, if we take $\mu \in \mathcal{P},$ and $\mu_n=\sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}}\mu([(k+1)/2^n;k/2^n[) \delta_{k/2^n},$ we have $(\mu_n)_n)$ converges weakly to $\mu,$ since for all bounded and continuous functions $f$ we have 
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)d\mu_n(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(\left \lfloor{x2^n}\right \rfloor/2^n)d\mu(x)$$
Can we use this to prove that $(\mathcal{P},d)$ is separable?

For the completeness, if we take a sequence $(\sigma_n)_n$ such that

$\forall \epsilon>0,\exists n_0 \in \mathbb{N};\forall p \geq n_0,q \geq n_0,d(\sigma_p,\sigma_q) \leq \epsilon,$ and here I am totally stuck.

Comment: For separability see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3115750/36150)

Comment: do you have ideas concerning the completeness ?

Comment: Well, have you tried anything? If you don't have any idea, then it might be worth a) using the search (which will lead you e.g. to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/164228/36150)) or b) taking a look at some books about this topic.

Comment: Following the hints in the link which you suggested, we can find a subsequence $u_{\phi(n)}$ such that $d(\mu_{\phi(n+1)},\mu_{\phi(n)}) <1/2^n,$ how to continue?